# how make communication between main main(main.js ) and javascript in webview in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm looking for making communication between mainwindow(main.js) and javascript in webview in electron,
using IPC renderer I can be able to send message to main but I can't be able to get message from main using ipcrenderer.on, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BroadcastChannel to resolve it. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API.
Recently I used the BroadcastChannel to communicate child view with parent, because I couldn't do it using IPC Renderer.

Comment: I'm looking for do it using electron

Comment: Yeah. I made it on a Electron app

Answer (score 0):

Main.js

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  
  // Needs to reply like this. Then you can listen this **asynchronous-reply** on your renderer
  event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})
```

Renderer.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
```

And if you are going to send message directly from main to the renderer.
`mainWindow.webContents.send("blablabla", args)` like this.